# Coverage test for standard library errors

Tags: unit-testing, go, error-handling

I've been trying to learn about Go's built-in testing framework and getting proper test coverage.

In one of the files I'm testing I'm only getting ~87% coverage:

`coverage: 87.5% of statements`

Here's a section of the code covered in the test:

```
// Check that the working directory is set
if *strctFlags.PtrWorkDir == "" {

// if the working directory is empty, set it to the current directory
strTemp, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    return "", errors.New("Could not get current working directory")
}

*strctFlags.PtrWorkDir = strTemp

} else if stat, err := os.Stat(*strctFlags.PtrWorkDir); err != nil ||
!stat.IsDir() {

    // Existence check of the work dir
    return "", errors.New("Specified directory \"" + *strctFlags.PtrWorkDir + "\" could not be found or was not a directory")
}

*strctFlags.PtrWorkDir, err = filepath.Abs(*strctFlags.PtrWorkDir)
if err != nil {
    return "", errors.New("Could not determine absolute filepath: " + err.Error())
}
```

The parts not covered in the test according to the .out file are the "if err != nil {}" blocks, which would be errors returned from standard library calls.

While I think the likelihood of the standard library passing errors would be slim unless there would be hardware failure, I think it would be good to know that the error is handled in the application properly. Also, checking returned errors is, to my understanding, idiomatic Go so I would think it would be good to be able to test error handling properly.

How do people handle testing errors like the situations above? Is it possible to get 100% coverage, or am I doing or structuring something incorrectly? Or do people skip testing those conditions?

Comment: [Some people skip them.](https://dev.to/danlebrero/the-tragedy-of-100-code-coverage). If you *must* have 100% test coverage for some reason, you should probably be mocking/stubbing out all of your stdlib calls.

Comment: Do the Go standard library packages have 100% test coverage? Do all other external packages have 100% test coverage? Do the OS calls have 100% test coverage. Does the hardware have 100% test coverage. Has all posible integer and floating-point arithmetic been tested? How long would this take? Bugs happen: [Intel Pentium FDIV bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug). And so on. 100% coverage testing is not possible.

Comment: For any non-trivial code (i.e. any code that uses I/O), 100% test coverage is a *literal impossibility*, as there are literally *an infinite number of code execution paths* (even assuming identical hardware, etc). So aiming for 100% coverage is a fool's errand. Although it is often possible to get test coverage tools, like that provided by Go, to report 100%. But that's not very meaningful, so it's not a worthy goal.

Comment: Why do you need 100% coverage?

Comment: @JoelCornett - Didn't mean to sound like it's necessary, I was asking if there's a common way to test that kind of scenario in an idiotmatic way for Go and how people usually handle that situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @flimzy explained in his answer, it is not good to aim for 100% coverage instead aim for useful test coverage.

Though you can test the system calls with slight modification to the code like this

```
package foo

// Get Working directory function
var osGetWd = os.Getwd

func GetWorkingDirectory() (string,error){
    strTemp, err := osGetWd() // Using the function defined above
    if err != nil {
       return "", errors.New("Could not get current working directory")
    return strTemp,nil
}
```

And while testing

```
package foo

func TestGetWdError() {
    // Mocked function for os.Getwd
    myGetWd := func() (string,error) {
      myErr := errors.New("Simulated error")
      return "",myErr
    }

    // Update the var to this mocked function
    osGetWd = myGetWd

   // This will return error
   val,err := GetWorkingDirectory()
}
```

This will help you to achieve 100% coverage

Comment: Looks like this was what I was looking for! I understand 100% test coverage isn't bulletproof and appreciate the pointers behind the philosophy of that viewpoint, but at the same time I feel like I've learned something about how the language works (I've not run into a situation where I can assign a variable to a function in this way before...)

Answer (score 4):

There are many non-hardware failure scenarios where most standard library functoins might fail. Whether you care to test those is another question.  For `os.Getwd()`, for instance, I might expect that call to fail if the working directory doesn't exist, (and you could go to the effort of testing this scenario).

What's probably more useful (and a better testing approach in general), would be to mock those calls, so that you can trigger errors during testing, just so that you can test your error-case code.

But please, for the love of code, don't aim for 100% test coverage.  Aim for *useful test coverage*.  It is possible to make a tool report 100% coverage without covering useful cases, and it is possible to cover useful cases without making the tool report 100%.

But *true* 100% coverage is a literal impossibility in most programs (even the simple "Hello World!"). So don't aim for it.

Comment: I kinda agree, but isn't it a downside of a coverage calculation solution then? I mean, if I covered 100% of my logic, then shouldn't the coverage reporting tool understand it, instead of just corny calculating the lines of code?

Comment: The downside is in pretending that any coverage tool's number means more than it means. It's a literal impossibility to cover "100% of logic" in any modern program, on a modern computer.

Comment: Programmers may understand it, but it's hard to explain it to project management or even customers (if they care about those metrics).

Comment: The fact that reality is hard to explain to project managers isn't something tools can fix.